# How to make a seed to pd.sample like np.random.seed?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe and I want to randomly select several columns from it. And I want to select the same columns every time. I find there is a seed moduel for numpy.random but I do not know any similar application in pandas.

Answer (score 34):

You can use a parameter random_state.  See example below taken from documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

```
df['num_legs'].sample(n=3, random_state=1)
```

It will ensure that 3 random data will be used every time you run it. Then you can change the value random_state as you want

Answer (score 1):

Passing `random_state` to `.sample()`, as @jose_bacoy suggested, is the simplest and best way to do it. Sometimes that isn't an option / would be awkward (e.g. it is in a complicated `groupby` aggregation using `pd.NamedAgg`, so can't pass parameters like `random_state`).

In that case, you can just use `np.random.seed` and it works perfectly well for pandas also.

Example:

```
np.random.seed(1)
pd.DataFrame(range(10)).sample(n=3)
```

always returns

```
   0
2  2
9  9
6  6
```